# Convert resource name of audio file to resource id

Tags: android, android-resources

My app reads insructions from xml file and execute them. 
One Of the instructions is an audio filename to play.
My xml may contain the sring @raw/filename or whatever you advice. 
Now once I read it in my app, how do i convert it to resource id which can be used with PediaPlayer object?

Comment: **R.java** creates an ID for all the resources present in the android application. Try using that.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
res = getResources().getIdentifier("filename without extension", "raw",packageName);
```

The raw is the resource type it can also be `String` or whatever.
You can use `getPackageName()` for packagename
Then simply

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, res);
mp.start();
```